# Knockout bind array of complex type with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a bootstrap nav-tab and I want to display dynamically content when I select a tab. Ajax returns an array of Results. Each result has Price,Logo,Companyname and an array of Covers. Each cover has Price,MaxCover,Optional and Description.
Rest of html code is here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560797/load-tabs-with-ajax) but now I want to return a more complex type.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var cover = new
    {
        Price: ko.observable(),
        MaxCover: ko.observable(),
        Optional: ko.observable(),
        Description: ko.observable(),
    }
var result = new
    {
        Price: ko.observable(),
        InsLogo: ko.observable(),
        CompanyName: ko.observable(),
        Covers: ko.observableArray()
    };

var tab = function (Id, name, selected) {
    this.Id = Id;
    this.name = name;
    this.Results = ko.observableArray();
    this.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return this === selected();
    }, this);
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedTab = ko.observable();
    self.tabs = ko.observableArray([
        new tab(0, 'Tab1', self.selectedTab),
        new tab(1, 'Tab2', self.selectedTab),
        new tab(2, 'Tab3', self.selectedTab)
    ]);
    self.selectedTab(self.tabs()[0]);

    self.selectedTab.subscribe(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSection")',
            data: { Id: self.selectedTab().Id },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                self.selectedTab().Results(data.Results); //Here I want to fill the results!!!!!!
            }
        });

    });

}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: any issue in particular you facing ? as far i see data isn't that complex . add a fiddle so i can help u with . cheers

Comment: You don't need to use `new` with object literals `{}` - in fact, that's an error. Using `{}` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is okay with a few small glitches. Some suggestions to improve it:

- Make your viewmodels so that they initialize themselves from a parameters object.
- Don't introduce dependencies between viewmodels when you don't have have to. I'm thinking of the `isSelected` property here, this can be taken care of in the view. For example, when inside a `foreach: tabs`: `data-bind="css: {selected: $data === $parent.selectedTab()}"`
- You have a timing issue: Subscribe to `selectedTab` first, *then* initialize it with `self.selectedTab(self.tabs()[0]);`. It should be obvious why. (Generally it's useful to split viewmodel creation into a "setup" and an "init" phase.)
- Only send an Ajax request for tab details when tab details are still empty.
- Subscribtions receive the new value of the observable as an argument, use it.
- Observables are functions:

  - If you want to store an Ajax response in them you can use them as a callback directly.
  - In the same way you can use them as an event handler:
    `data-bind="click: $parent.selectedTab"`.
- JS convention is to use `PascalCase` for constructor names (like in viewmodels) and `camelCase` for all other identifiers.

With all that, we get:

```
function Tab(data) {
    this.Id = data.Id;
    this.name = data.name;
    this.Results = ko.observableArray();
}
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    // setup
    self.selectedTab = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTab.subscribe(function (selectedTab) {
        if (selectedTab.Results()) return;
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetSection")', {Id: selectedTab.Id}).done(selectedTab.Results);
    });

    // init
    self.tabs = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.tabs, function (tabData) {
        return new Tab(tabData);
    }));
    self.selectedTab(self.tabs()[0]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel({
    tabs: [
        {Id: 0, name: 'Tab1'},
        {Id: 1, name: 'Tab2'},
        {Id: 2, name: 'Tab3'}
    ]
}));
```

To convert plain data structures that come from the server (like your array results and covers) into a structure of viewmodels, observables and observable arrays I recommend looking into the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).